# Filter user details using user ID

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I pass a user ID from front end, I need to fetch all the user Details from the Django rest model to the corresponding view.

```
class UserDetails(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id',None)
        //*queryset = UserModel.objects.all()*
        //instead of getting all the objects from UserModel, I need to get the particular user_id object only
        return querysest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
class UserDetails(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id')
        if user_id:
           return UserModel.objects.filter(id=user_id).first()
        return UserModel.objects.none()
```

Comment: but why should  I use first() in this case?

Comment: i thought you want get only 1 user. And `.filter()` return a queryset. So i use `.first()`

Comment: using first() seems more helpful now. great answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to try to get `user_id` param from **URL**.

And then try to filter from **queryset** on the basis of obtained `user_id`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    # Get queryset of User Model
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()

    # Try to fetch the user_id param from url
    user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)

    # If user_id param is not None, filter using the obtained user_id
    if user_id is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(id=user_id)

    return queryset
```

Comment: That was a very useful, valid answer. I have a few doubt too. Can we define `queryset` in a user defined function? or somewhere in a function based view ?

Comment: Second doubt, can I user `queryset` inside a `post()` function ?

Comment: @Sreenath queryset can be used in post function. But I will not suggest to use it in `function based` views. In function based view just process and pass to template directly. And one more thing you don't need to use `.first()` as when you filter with `id` you will always get only one result.

Comment: And also you need to pass `None`. Coz in case URL parameter doesn't have `user_id` it will throw the error.

Comment: The reason why I prefer `first()` is, otherwise it returns an array of `queryset`